# Telerik RadDock on left side of main form in Winform application

Tags: winforms, telerik, raddocking

I have a WinForm application that I would like to add a RadDoc like a popup menu on the left inside form main.
The user should be able to hover to the left side of the screen or click some tab on the left side of the screen and then the menu bar will appear.
The RadDock control itself does not have a auto hide.
I can hide the ToolWindow inside the RadDock but this leaves a blue background where the ToolWindow would show.
Also, when the ToolWindows are "AutoHide" they are tabbed at the bottom but they need to be tabbed vertically on the left.
The last thing is that I can't seem to set the "popup" size of the ToolWindows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you go through the RadDock documentation.

- Auto Hide article: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-architecture-and-features-auto-hiding-windows.html
- Arranging windows: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-architecture-and-features-arranging-dockwindows.html
- Modifying windows size: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-object-model-example-building-an-advanced-layout-at-runtime.html

To make the whole control collapsible, you can use the RadCollapsiblePanel control: [link.](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/panels-and-labels-collapsible-panel-overview.html)

Comment: These are settings for the toolwindows inside the RadDock. I need to slide the RadDock control itself.

Comment: RadCollapsiblePanel is what I needed. Thanks.